# Why protected final field is null when source code says otherwise during Mockito test?

Tags: java, android, junit, android-recyclerview, mockito

I created test using Mockito 1.10.19 for testing custom RecyclerView adapter. (Code has been simplified to remove information noise, leaving simplest version that still have the issue)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder> {

    private final Dependency dependency;

    public CustomAdapter(@NonNull Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void refreshData() {
        dependency.refreshData();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ingredients_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        dependency.bind(holder, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dependency.getItemsCount();
    }
}
```

I've injected mocked dependencies to it, but adapter is otherwise untouched.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomAdapterTest {

    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    @Mock
    private Dependecy dependencyMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(dependencyMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRefreshData() throws Exception {
        adapter.refreshData();
        verify(dependencyMock).refreshData();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(dependencyMock);
    }
}
```

When running very simple test 'testRefreshData()' adapter calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This causes `NullPointerException` to be thrown.

at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyChanged(RecyclerView.java:10763)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(RecyclerView.java:6342)

This happens in code:

```
static class AdapterDataObservable extends Observable<AdapterDataObserver> {
    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return !mObservers.isEmpty();
    }
public void notifyChanged() {
    // since onChanged() is implemented by the app, it could do anything, including
    // removing itself from {@link mObservers} - and that could cause problems if
    // an iterator is used on the ArrayList {@link mObservers}.
    // to avoid such problems, just march thru the list in the reverse order.
    for (int i = mObservers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        mObservers.get(i).onChanged();
    }
}
```

When derefencing `mObservers`. This should not happen since `Observable<T>` defines `mObservers` as final and initialized:

```
public abstract class Observable<T> {
    /**
     * The list of observers.  An observer can be in the list at most
     * once and will never be null.
     */
    protected final ArrayList<T> mObservers = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Why does this happen? It this some sort of bug or known limitation? How can I work around this? (Not counting Robolectric, I've decided to stop using it since it has problems of its own)

Before anyone asks; this happens only during test, code that is tested works just fine.

Version used: JUnit 4.12. Mockito 1.10.19, Support libraries 25.0.0, Android Studio 2.2.2, jdk 1.8.0_112,

Comment: can you provide full class code for CustomAdapter ?

Comment: Updated question as per request adding full class code (simplified) that contains the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably happens because you attempt to test code which depend on Android framework classes using JUnit.

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40323510/2463035) to another question which is related to exactly the same issue.

Comment: You are correct.
While RecyclerView.Adapter is not stubbed because its a part of recyclerview-v7; it depends on Observable which is. Its a part of android SDK android.jar. I guess back to the drawing board, but it doesn't look like I will be able to test without Robolectric any time soon.

Comment: @st1hy, I tend to agree - no chance. I'm very into unit testing, but I simply abandoned the idea of testing UI logic on Android because it is 1) too complicated 2) has very low ROI - UI logic is easily testable manually (though you need to have a clear separation between UI and business logic for this)