# Android Bundle simple unit test not working

Tags: android

I'm quite new to android and trying to understand how bundle works.

I get blocked by the following unit test. Can someone please explain why it fails ?

```
@Test
public void testBundle() throws Exception {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String key = "hello";
    String value = "world";
    bundle.putString(key, value);
    Assert.assertEquals(value, bundle.getString(key));
}

junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :world
Actual   :null
```

Comment: What environment are you using? Instrumentation Test, Robolectric, JUnit, other?

Comment: Hi vasiliy junit test

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JUnit tests run on a local machine which doesn't have all the Android source code present, but just stub classes (described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html)). These stub classes allow you to compile your Android app against them (because their API is identical to the actual Android framework), but they do not contain any logic in order to make them "light".

By default, if you attempt to invoke any of the stub methods you get an exception. Something like this:

```
public Bundle() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

this "fail fast" approach was employed in order to prevent developers from accidentally running their code against these stub classes and then wondering why it doesn't work.

However, this behavior can be changed with this configuration in `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

this makes the stub methods return default value instead of throwing exceptions.

You probably have this feature enabled, therefore when you run your JUnit tests you don't get exception, but `Bundle#getString()` method just returns default value (which is `null`).

If you want to test code that has Android framework dependencies, you should do either of:

1. Mock these dependencies (e.g. Mockito)
2. Run tests with Robolectric
3. Run instrumentation tests on Android device

In any case, `unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true` is a VERY DANGEROUS feature to use, because it makes your tests non-reliable: some test can pass because a default value was returned by stub method, but the functionality will fail on a real device. Turn it off.

Comment: indeed, i have this option enabled!

Comment: @HuiWang then you should definitely disable it, and then consider accepting the answer )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I really appreciate it. Another question, would it be possible to run an instrumented test without emulator ? This allows me to run tests in a CI

Comment: @HuiWang, there are some "devices farms" which have various devices and expose API that allows you to upload APKs to one or more of their devices, run an instrumentation tests, and get test results back. This process can be automated and executed during CI, but I never used it myself. Maybe you should ask another question on this topic

Answer (score 4):

As described in [Building Local Unit Tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies),

> By default, the Android Plug-in for Gradle executes your local unit
>   tests against a modified version of the android.jar library, which
>   does not contain any actual code.

Your test code runs against a stripped version of `Bundle` which doesn't contain the actual implementation, hence you get `null` whenever you try to get something from it. If you actually want to test the behavior of a `Bundle`, I'd suggest writing an instrumentation test which runs on an Android device against the real `Bundle` implementation.

Comment: Thanks Egor, your answer is helpful but Vasiliy's is more complete. Thanks :)